# How can I use Gnome shell's menus in Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, customization

I am messing with Unity and trying to tweak everything in order to have a more customized desktop.

Using Gnome Shell, anyone can see that the menus are different in the top panel. They have transparency and look like a bubble sort of. You know what I am talking about, right?

Is there a way I could use the same menus for Unity or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but it is not possible. Unity uses GTK to draw the dropdown menus, and GNOME Shell uses CSS.