# Get Unity 8 Menu Bar on GNOME?

Tags: unity, gnome

I recently checked out Unity 8 on my Ubuntu 16.10 system, and I didn't like much but when I went to log out I was amazed by the menu bar and I'd like to get that menu bar in GNOME, which is my primary environment. Is this possible at all? Or is there an alternative that is similar?

[Here is a screenshot of the menu bar I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIn0L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity and Gnome use completely different rendering formats.

From this answer: [How can I use Gnome shell's menus in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103972/how-can-i-use-gnome-shells-menus-in-unity?rq=1)

> Unity uses GTK to draw the dropdown menus, and GNOME Shell uses CSS.